# md-autocomplete (HEAD:master) not displayed http response

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the latest version of [material.angular](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/#/) and i have the following directive (md-autocomplete):

```
<md-autocomplete flex
    md-no-cache="true"
    md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="vm.searchText"
    md-items="item in vm.querySearch(vm.searchText)"
    md-item-text="item.id"
    md-min-length="0"
    md-floating-label="Búsqueda Opileak"
    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">

    <md-item-template>
        <span class="item-title">
            <md-icon class="fa  fa-circle-o"></md-icon>
            <span> {{item.id}} </span>
        </span>
        <span class="item-metadata">
            <span class="item-metastat">
                    <strong>{{item.q}}</strong> q
            </span>
            <span class="item-metastat">
                    <strong>{{item.active}}</strong> active
            </span>
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The following code in the controller (ignore the text, i am always responding the same data for testing):

```
    vm.querySearch   = querySearch;
    vm.searchText = "";
    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************
   function querySearch(text){
        DataService.getOpileakSearches().then(function(response){
            console.log(response.searches);
            return response.searches;
        });
   }
```

And i get the right data in 'response.searches', my console is displaying:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 10315,
    "name": "13@@ayudaenaccion",
    "q": "@ayudaenaccion",
    "src": [
      "TWITTER",
      "TWITTER"
    ],
    "src_type": null,
    "start_interval": null,
    "end_interval": null,
    "location": null,
    "geolocation": "",
    "active": true
  },
  {
    "id": 10316,
    "name": "13@apadrinar",
    "q": "apadrinar",
    "src": [
      "TWITTER",
      "TWITTER"
    ],
    "src_type": null,
    "start_interval": null,
    "end_interval": null,
    "location": null,
    "geolocation": "",
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 10317,
    "name": "13@ong",
    "q": "ong",
    "src": [
      "TWITTER",
      "TWITTER"
    ],
    "src_type": null,
    "start_interval": null,
    "end_interval": null,
    "location": null,
    "geolocation": "",
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 10327,
    "name": "13@ayudaenaccion",
    "q": "ayudaenaccion",
    "src": [
      "TWITTER",
      "TWITTER"
    ],
    "src_type": null,
    "start_interval": null,
    "end_interval": null,
    "location": null,
    "geolocation": "",
    "active": true
  }
]
```

But md-autocomplete dont show anything and no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method in controller like this

```
$scope.querySearch = function(text){
    return DataService.getOpileakSearches().then(function(response){
        console.log(response.searches);
        return response.searches;
    });
```

}